# Gitlab-CI: how to avoid services config duplication between jobs?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have the following jobs configuration in `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
job1:
  stage: test
  services:
    - name: mariadb
      alias: mysql
      entrypoint: [""]
      command: [...]

  script:
    - ...

job2:
  stage: test
  services:
    - name: mariadb
      alias: mysql
      entrypoint: [""]
      command: [...]

  script:
    - ...

job3:
  stage: test
  services:
    - name: mariadb
      alias: mysql
      entrypoint: [""]
      command: [...]

  script:
    - ...
```

`services` portion is the same for all 3 jobs.

Is it possible to avoid this duplication?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can also utilize Anchors YAML feature - https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#anchors .

```
.job_template: &job_definition
  services:
    - name: mariadb
      alias: mysql
      entrypoint: [""]
      command: [...]

job1:
  <<: *job_definition
  stage: test
```

When the config is common for all jobs, use global service. When you want to avoid duplication among only some jobs, use YAML anchors.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `extends` which was introduced in **GitLab 11.3**. It is an alternative to using [YAML anchors](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#anchors) and is a little more flexible and readable.

```
.db_services:
  services:
    - name: mariadb
      alias: mysql
      entrypoint: [""]
      command: [...]

job1:
  extends: .db_services
  stage: test
...
```

Source: [Using extends in Gitlab CI](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#extends)

Answer (score 1):

Just define it outside the jobs: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#define-image-and-services-from-gitlab-ci-yml

```
services:
    - name: mariadb
      alias: mysql
      entrypoint: [""]
      command: [...]

job1:
  stage: test
  script:
    - ...

job2:
  stage: test
  script:
    - ...

job3:
  stage: test
  script:
    - ...
```

Comment: I have more jobs in this config file, and not all of them require this service (in fact, it takes quite some time to start it). If I move service configuration to the top level, will it be started for any job, or there is a way to start it just for some jobs (and if yes, how?)?

Comment: I think this it not possible yet. You can define global servies, which are available for all jobs (like before_script) or you can define it separatley for a single job